# What is the chance of a block of 4 mines in minesweeper?

Tags: probability

Given an $m$ by $n$ minesweeper board with $k$ mines, how would you calculate the chance of at least 1 block of 4 mines appearing in a square? This is assuming the mines are distributed randomly, of course.

For example, my friend and I would always imagine their would *never* be a block of 4 mines on the expert mode $16$ by $30$ with $99$ mines. Although the statistical probability seems to be roughly 50%.

[image: Block of 4 mines]

Comment: With a computer program. Unless $m,n$ are very small, it's not feasible to do by hand. Even with a computer program, an exact probability for $m=n=100$ is probably not  doable. A simulation is the fallback method.

Comment: @quasi, That's true, although I wonder if there is a general solution.

Comment: No, forget it -- there's no such solution. Algorithm, yes. General formula or recursion, no. Can I prove that? No. Would I bet against a general solution. Yes. How much? Well ... not that much -- I couild be wrong.

Comment: If you want to try, I suggest first getting formulas for fixed, small $k$, (but arbitrary $m,n$). Of course, the probability is zero if $k<4$, and it should be easy to calculate for the case $k=4$ -- try it. Maybe you can progress to slightly higher values of $k$, but by the time you reach $k=12$ (if you reach it), you'll want to give up.

Comment: @quasi, Well why not I guess, I'll give it a shot.